What does "over" mean in "There's the airplane ticket over" mean?
I'm watching the movie "Rear Window" by Alfred Hitchcock and there is a scene in which the main character tries to estimate the price of a dress his girlfriend is wearing. She is a famous person who never wears the same dress twice because 'it's expected of her'. She tells this character that she just came in a plane from Paris in that dress and asks him whether the dress will sell. He responds:

That depends on the quote. There's the airplane ticket over and import duties, hidden taxes, profit markup...

Does over in this context mean:

over (adverb)
on top of, additionally (Wiktionary)

It's weird but I could only find this sole definition of this adverb fitting this context  only in the Wiktionary. Everywhere else the only thing fitting this context was the phrase over and above. Seems strange that such a common usage of a word would be so hard to find.

So in this case it's just definition 1f or a from here: "over" the Atlantic Ocean, or we might use it generally for any trip or movement ("come over here").

Classic movie. Looking forward to some more questions about it :-) Use Merriam-Webster, would be my suggestion. “Over.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over. Accessed 17 Oct. 2024.

I  think that - The purpose of having a scene in the film with the main characters discussing a dress selling price is to derive humour and not teach arithmetic to the viewers  (The heroine has no intention of starting an import-export business). The movie is peppered with humorous exchanges, making it a delight to watch.

Wow !!!! I've stumbled upon a groundbreaking reinterpretation of 'Rear Window'! Apparently, Jeff and Lisa are seriously calculating the dress cost and flying over the Atlantic". They discovered that flying over to Paris to buy a dress was a goldmine. Who needs photography and modeling when you can become international dress importers? How to start a lucrative business is the movie's hidden theme."

Andy Bonner's 'over the Atlantic' seems wholly correct… as do 'come over here…' or 'go over there…' and as would a ticket 'out' or 'back' or 'home…'

In isolation "the airplane ticket over" could mean in excess, as you say, but the context makes it clear that it means the ticket for the plane "over" from Paris. This fits with the definition of over as an adverb meaning something like "to the other side" (from Chambers).

Apparently she's a fashion model. The cost of flying the dress 'over' from Paris would affect its price in America.

@Kate. I thought she came over with the dress, but on closer reading she may be talking about importing more of the same dress to sell. The definition of "over" in the context still stands though.

@timchessish Oh, I was thinking that this could be the meaning but for some reason dissmissed it, heh. Thanks.

@timchessish - Yes, I agree; I was just clarifying OP's reference to her as a 'famous person'. (An attempt to edit my comment failed for technical reasons.) It's not clear why he says 'ticket' if they're talking about imports; maybe she bought the dress she had modelled in order to re-sell it.

over there is a locative preposition, referring to the trip across the ocean, from Paris to the US. This is perfectly idiomatic English.
If you're on one side of a creek or small river, having a picnic or party on the grassy bank, and happen to see some acquaintances in a canoe or kayak on the other side, you can yell "C'mon over, join the party!"
Compare:

Since I am in San Fransciso, I can't visit you in France at a moment's notice. The price of a ticket over would be really high if it isn't purchased well in advance.


To clarify the idiom in this case "the airplane ticket over" is short for "the airplane ticket from over there to here."

@MarkHu  We don't typically buy airplane tickets for a dress but ship it.  An airplane ticket would be for a person. So it's quite possible this means you'd have to fly to Paris (and back) to consummate the purchase of a number of these dresses (or did already fly there and back) and that cost would have to be factored into the price.  But it's just banter in any case, and the precise details are not relevant.

OP has a query on a dialogue from the movie, Rear window:

That depends on the quote. There's the airplane ticket over and import duties, hidden taxes, profit markup...
Everywhere else the only thing fitting this context was the phrase over and above.

OP has given the background in which the dialogue is used, which is helpful to find the meaning of the dialogue.
OP has stated an idiom "over and above", which is exactly how over is used in the current situation. The adverb has many meanings and it can lead to confusion (not appreciating humour).

Reference OALD (Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary).
IDM over and above besides sth; in addi- tion to sth:
The waiters get good tips over and above their wages.
There are other factors over and above those we have discussed.

Explanation of the use of "over":

That depends on the quote.
Whether you get a buyer or not depends on what price you are going to sell (it's going to be expensive)

There's the airplane ticket over and import duties, hidden taxes, profit markup...
The costs adds up import duties, hidden taxes, profit markup... Over and above the plane ticket..
The 1954 Alfred Hitchcock film Rear Window is set in Greenwich Village, New York City, and the story takes place in a fictional apartment building at 125 W. Ninth Street.
L.B. Jefferies' girlfriend, Lisa Carol Fremont, had travelled to Paris. Jeff humorously asks Lisa, to consider adding the flight ticket from Paris to New York, as an additional cost ('over and above/ over') of the dress.(the other normal costs like import duties, hidden taxes, and profit markup). This would make the dress too expensive and hence unsaleable.
Lisa's travel to Paris was for some other purpose (not for buying the dress) hence Jeff's suggestion is illogical and playful.


Edit - 1.
The explanation accompanying the right answers or in the comments doesn't match the storyline. (She wants to import more dresses etc).
I was going to delete my answer as I found it was a waste of time. Then I saw Kate Bunting's comments -
"It's not clear why he says 'ticket' if they're talking about imports".
This comment is similar to my initial thoughts-
"Why should Alfred Hitchcock include a meaningless scene where the movie's main characters discuss a dress selling price?.
If you interpret "the airplane ticket over" as "the airplane flying over the Atlantic" or "the airplane flying to Paris" the intended humour is lost.   It implies that the characters are seriously calculating the cost price. (No relevance to the story's script).
Instead if you consider over" means an "excess amount" - it maintains the original wit.
